# OpenCV Camera Calibration Parsing Error. How to solve it?

Tags: c++, opencv, camera, configuration-files, camera-calibration

I'm using the camera calibration source code from OpenCV in this link http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/calib3d/camera_calibration/camera_calibration.html

In the configuration file may choose to use camera as an input, a video file or an image list.So I choose camera. So I tried to create a configuration file.

Here’s my XML configuration file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<opencv_storage>
<Settings>
<!-- Number of inner corners per a item row and column. (square, circle) -->
<BoardSize_Width>9</BoardSize_Width>
<BoardSize_Height>6</BoardSize_Height>
<!-- The size of a square in some user defined metric system (pixel, millimeter)-->
<Square_Size>50</Square_Size>
<!-- The type of input used for camera calibration. One of: CHESSBOARD CIRCLES_GRID ASYMMETRIC_CIRCLES_GRID -->
<Calibrate_Pattern>"CHESSBOARD"</Calibrate_Pattern>
<!-- The input to use for calibration. To use an input camera -> give the ID of the camera, like "1" To use an input video -> give the path of the input video, like "/tmp/x.avi" To use an image list -> give the path to the XML or YAML file containing the list of the images, like "/tmp/circles_list.xml" -->
<Input>3</Input>
<!-- If true (non-zero) we flip the input images around the horizontal axis.-->
<Input_FlipAroundHorizontalAxis>0</Input_FlipAroundHorizontalAxis>
<!-- Time delay between frames in case of camera. -->
<Input_Delay>100</Input_Delay>
<!-- How many frames to use, for calibration. -->
<Calibrate_NrOfFrameToUse>25</Calibrate_NrOfFrameToUse>
<!-- Consider only fy as a free parameter, the ratio fx/fy stays the same as in the input cameraMatrix. Use or not setting. 0 - False Non-Zero - True-->
<Calibrate_FixAspectRatio> 1 </Calibrate_FixAspectRatio>
<!-- If true (non-zero) tangential distortion coefficients are set to zeros and stay zero.-->
<Calibrate_AssumeZeroTangentialDistortion>1</Calibrate_AssumeZeroTangentialDistortion>
<!-- If true (non-zero) the principal point is not changed during the global optimization.-->
<Calibrate_FixPrincipalPointAtTheCenter> 1 </Calibrate_FixPrincipalPointAtTheCenter>
<!-- The name of the output log file. -->
<Write_outputFileName>"out_camera_data.xml"</Write_outputFileName>
<!-- If true (non-zero) we write to the output file the feature points.-->
<Write_DetectedFeaturePoints>1</Write_DetectedFeaturePoints>
<!-- If true (non-zero) we write to the output file the extrinsic camera parameters.-->
<Write_extrinsicParameters>1</Write_extrinsicParameters>
<!-- If true (non-zero) we show after calibration the undistorted images.-->
<Show_UndistortedImage>1</Show_UndistortedImage>
</Settings>
</opencv_storage>
```

The camera Id is 3. When run the code I got this error: `OpenCV Error: Parsing error <C:/Calibration/CameraCalibration/config1.xml<16>: Preliminary end of the stream> in icvXMLParseTag`

I don't understand what is the problem. Is it the chesssboard size? How should I chose the BoardSize_Width and BoardSize_Height?

Comment: sorry no. I missed the end. Modified the config file. But not I got other error : Inexistent input: Invalid input detected.

Comment: Please update the question to include the new error.

Comment: I assume that you're using some sample code to load your config file, given that you're getting suspiciously-spelled error messages like "inexistent input"?

Comment: Should I post new question? Now the problem gone Its Ok. now giving no error. Its ok by <Input>"0"</Input>. But its open Image View , but then do nothing. Image view is all grey. Doesn't show the chessboard. What is the problem?

Comment: This sounds like a new question.

Comment: should I post a new one?